# How can I zoom an image while using react-image-crop? Or is there other library to achieve the same

Tags: reactjs, zooming, crop

I have to add crop image feature. I have used the `react-image-crop` to crop the specific part of the image. But now I need to zoom in the image and then crop the specific zoomed part of the image. How can I add zoom feature using `react-image-crop`? Or is there an alternate to `react-image-crop`?

Comment: Cropper works? https://github.com/roadmanfong/react-cropper

Comment: @Jebin ,Thank you for the suggestion. I am trying the same now. But I am facing issue with the image. The image is from a remote server and i am getting cross -origin-error. I cannot fix this by adding headers at the source as it is not handled by us.Need a solution to fix this. With a static image residing inside the project the react-cropper works well.But for the image from remote server react-cropper is not getting applied because of cross origin error

Comment: Cross origin is a completely different issue. Figure out a way to get past CORS. If you can write code for backend, download the image in your server which will get past CORS. Then serve it as local and then you can crop.

Answer (score 1):

I am using react-image-crop. I can zoom the upload picture and crop it. After cropping, cropped image is displayed below of the original image. Here is the example:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import ReactCrop from 'react-image-crop';
import 'react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.css';

import './App.css';

class CropImage extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    src: null,
    crop: {
      unit: '%',
      width: 30,
      aspect: 16 / 9,
    },
  };

  onSelectFile = e => {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener('load', () =>
        this.setState({ src: reader.result })
      );
      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  };

  // If you setState the crop in here you should return false.
  onImageLoaded = image => {
    this.imageRef = image;
  };

  onCropComplete = crop => {
    this.makeClientCrop(crop);
  };

  onCropChange = (crop, percentCrop) => {
    // You could also use percentCrop:
    // this.setState({ crop: percentCrop });
    this.setState({ crop });
  };

  async makeClientCrop(crop) {
    if (this.imageRef && crop.width && crop.height) {
      const croppedImageUrl = await this.getCroppedImg(
        this.imageRef,
        crop,
        'newFile.jpeg'
      );
      this.setState({ croppedImageUrl });
    }
  }

  getCroppedImg(image, crop, fileName) {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const scaleX = image.naturalWidth / image.width;
    const scaleY = image.naturalHeight / image.height;
    canvas.width = crop.width;
    canvas.height = crop.height;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.drawImage(
      image,
      crop.x * scaleX,
      crop.y * scaleY,
      crop.width * scaleX,
      crop.height * scaleY,
      0,
      0,
      crop.width,
      crop.height
    );

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      canvas.toBlob(blob => {
        if (!blob) {
          //reject(new Error('Canvas is empty'));
          console.error('Canvas is empty');
          return;
        }
        blob.name = fileName;
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.fileUrl);
        this.fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        resolve(this.fileUrl);
      }, 'image/jpeg');
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { crop, croppedImageUrl, src } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={this.onSelectFile} />
        </div>
        {src && (
          <ReactCrop
            src={src}
            crop={crop}
            ruleOfThirds
            onImageLoaded={this.onImageLoaded}
            onComplete={this.onCropComplete}
            onChange={this.onCropChange}
          />
        )}
        {croppedImageUrl && (
          <img alt="Crop" style={{ maxWidth: '100%' }} src={croppedImageUrl} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CropImage
```

**Example for zooming image:**

```
import Cropper from 'react-easy-crop'
import React from "react";

class ZoomAndCropImage extends React.Component {
    state = {
        image: 'https://ec.europa.eu/programmes/creative-europe/sites/creative-europe/files/covid19-cdc-unsplash.jpg',
        crop: {x: 10, y: 10},
        zoom: 1,
        aspect: 4 / 3,
    };

    onCropChange = crop => {
        this.setState({crop})
    };

    onCropComplete = (croppedArea, croppedAreaPixels) => {
        console.log(croppedArea, croppedAreaPixels)
    };

    onZoomChange = zoom => {
        console.log(zoom, 'zoom');
        this.setState({zoom})
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Cropper
                    image={this.state.image}
                    crop={this.state.crop}
                    zoom={this.state.zoom}
                    aspect={this.state.aspect}
                    onCropChange={this.onCropChange}
                    onCropComplete={this.onCropComplete}
                    onZoomChange={this.onZoomChange}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ZoomAndCropImage
```

Comment: thanks!! The zoom happening here is with respect to the page in which the image is selected for cropping. Since only the image is present in the page it looks like the image is zooming, but actually it the page zooming out. In my case i have other components built in the page level, so if i zoom in, it is zooming my page rather than the image with react-image-crop.I need only the image to zoom in not the whole page

Comment: hi @Raagavi, I added another example for zooming image, please have a look. hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you Khabir. I tried this approach earlier, but the requirement that did not match for me i, the crop box is not movable , but the image is. So here we can zoom the image , move the image around the container but the crop box position is fixed which is a problem in my case. Found a module called react-cropper, but not sure it will also work as i expect.